# Where Clause in Entity Framework not returning Correct Result

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

This EF thing does not seem an easy route for me as a beginner :(. I have following SQL which gives 20 records:

```
SELECT 
    Suppliers.SupplierName, 
    srma.Id, 
    srma.CreatedOn, 
    srmaStatuses.StatusName,
    srma.Status,
    srma.PONumber,
    srma.PONumber, 
    PurchaseOrders.PODate, 
    PurchaseOrders.suppliersOrderNumber 
FROM 
    SRMAs srma 
    join srmastatuses on srma.status = srmastatuses.id 
    JOIN PurchaseOrders  on SRMA.PONumber = PurchaseOrders.PONumber 
    JOIN Suppliers on Suppliers.SupplierID = PurchaseOrders.SupplierID 
WHERE 
    srma.Status in (0,1) 
    AND(PurchaseOrders.suppliersOrderNumber LIKE '%2002%' OR   srma.PONumber = '2002')
```

I made the following LINQ version which is not returning any record:

```
var searchQuery = collection["query"].Trim();

DBContext_Model db = new DBContext_Model();
int[] ids = new int[] { 0, 1 };
//LINQ way to JOIN tables
var srmas = (
    from SRMAs in db.SRMAs
    join SRMAStatus in db.SRMAStatus on SRMAs.Id equals SRMAStatus.Id
    join PurchaseOrders in db.PurchaseOrders on SRMAs.PONumber equals PurchaseOrders.PONumber
    join Suppliers in db.Suppliers on PurchaseOrders.SupplierID equals Suppliers.SupplierID
    join SRMADetails in db.SRMADetails on SRMAs.Id equals SRMADetails.SRMAId
    where
    (
        ids.Contains(SRMAs.Status)
        &&
            (
                searchQuery.Contains(PurchaseOrders.suppliersOrderNumber)
                ||
                searchQuery.Contains(SqlFunctions.StringConvert((decimal)SRMAs.PONumber))
            )
     )
     select new 
     { 
         SRMAs.Status,SRMAs.Id, 
         SRMAs.PONumber, 
         SRMAs.CreatedOn, 
         Suppliers.SupplierName, 
         SRMAStatus.StatusName, 
         PurchaseOrders.PODate, 
         PurchaseOrders.suppliersOrderNumber 
     }).ToList();
```

If I remove this part still it returns only 4 Record though it should do 20.

```
&&
(
    searchQuery.Contains(PurchaseOrders.suppliersOrderNumber)
    ||
    searchQuery.Contains(SqlFunctions.StringConvert((decimal)SRMAs.PONumber))
)
```

Is it possible to use LINQ rather than messing my life?

Comment: this part `SRMAs.Id equals SRMAStatus.Id`, shouldn't it be `SRMAs.StatusId equals SRMAStatus.Id` ?

Comment: Embarrassing for me, yes :(

Comment: @YuliamChandra Even then, block after `&&` is not returning results.

Comment: error `Error 23 Instance argument: cannot convert from 'int' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<string>`

Comment: what is the type of `PurchaseOrders.suppliersOrderNumber` and `SRMAs.PONumber` ?

Comment: @YuliamChandra it is integer

Comment: Use SQL, EF is a drag on your system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** The `on` clause should compare FK to PK, you were comparing PK to PK when joining `SRMA` with `SRMAStatus`. Change `SRMAs.Id equals SRMAStatus.Id` to `SRMAs.StatusId equals SRMAStatus.Id`.

**2.** Remove this part `join SRMADetails in db.SRMADetails on SRMAs.Id equals SRMADetails.SRMAId` since the sql query doesn't have join clause to SRMADetails.

**3.** And the search query you had at the moment will generate something like:

```
CAST(CHARINDEX(PurchaseOrders.suppliersOrderNumber, '2002') AS int) > 0
or
CAST(CHARINDEX(cast(SRMAs.PONumber as varchar(max)), '2002') AS int) > 0
```

Where it should be:

```
PurchaseOrders.suppliersOrderNumber.Contains(searchQuery)
||
SqlFunctions.StringConvert((decimal)SRMAs.PONumber).Contains(searchQuery)
```

So that it generates something like:

```
PurchaseOrders.suppliersOrderNumber LIKE '%2002%'
||
srma.PONumber LIKE '%2002%'
```